# Jekyll: Generate an include once and include it to all pages

Tags: html, include, jekyll, liquid

TL;DR: Can I say somehow to generate the content for a `{% include %}` once and just stamp it out in multiple places without having to regenerate it in every location?

I'm building a fairly big documentation site with Jekyll which has right now a bit over 50 articles on it. It has a sidebar where all articles are listed. the sidebar is built in a separate sidebar.html and then it is included into every page on the site with `{% include sidebar.html %}` in default.html.

The problem I have is that every single article runs the generation of sidebar.html separately, so I have over 50 generation passes on that piece of code. Every article I add adds another pass to this and make all the passes a bit slower, as generating the sidebar has to parse every single article in the project.

Build time has gone up from basically zero to over 100 seconds already, and if I remove the `{% include sidebar.html %}` then it drops down to 5 seconds. When I get all the articles in I'd estimate to have around 100-200 of them. Then I should have versioning in the future for all articles which means that there can easily be 1000+ articles in the long run. At that point I wouldn't be suprised if changing one letter in one file would take something like an hour to regenerate files in `jekyll serve`and `jekyll build`.

What I would like to do is to build sidebar.html once in the beginning of the build process and just stamp it out to every page when i generate said pages. Is this possible?

Comment: Generating a 50 article table of content doesn't takes so long. Can you show the code for you include ?

Comment: I put it up on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/KBKbQr4P. I explained there in short why it does what it does and noted some perfo issues already there, but I haven't figure a better way to do it. It is divided in three parts. Any suggestions on how to do that better is also appreciated.

Comment: That's a functional table of content ! I'll dig in this evening.

Comment: Nice liquid code. I understand that generating this can take long. I've tried nearly the same with 1000 pages, it a nightmare. I clearly can't find a workaround in pure liquid. Does you workflow can support a plugin or a rake task ?

Comment: It sure can but I'm not familiar with those. Also everything is quite open so I can change how it is generated. I thought about a one-time generation as I could then do the highlighting and style applying in javascript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now a better way to do this, thanks to Ben Balter.

instead of:  {% **include** yourtemplate.html %}
use:         {% **include_cached** yourtemplate.html %}

When used on larger items that need to be built once, such as a site hierarchy, the item will be cached.   For other items that vary across pages, you'll still want to use the include as you always have done.

It is explained well here:  https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-include-cache

Definitely cuts down on site startup time!

Answer (score 5):

Fastest way to do this.

Move `_includes/sidebar.html` to `sidebar-template.html`

Add this front matter :

```
---
layout: null
permalink: sidebar-template.html
---
```

Create a `Rakefile`

```
TPL = "_site/sidebar-template.html"
TST = "_includes/sidebar.html"

task :default => :nav

desc "Generates sidebar then copy it to be used as an include"
task :nav do

  if !File.exist?(TST)
    puts "Creating dummy #{TST} file"
    open(TST, 'w') do |f|
      f.puts warning
    end
  end

  puts "Building Jekyll 1st run"
  system "jekyll build --trace"

  # delete target file (TST) if exist
  if File.exist?(TST)
      puts "#{TST} exists deleting it"
      rm TST
  end

  # copy generated file as an include
  cp(TPL, TST)

  puts "Building Jekyll AGAIN"
  system "jekyll build --trace"

  puts "task END"
end
```

Just run `rake` and you have your sidebar include generated.

Comment: This might work but to me it is a hack to work around limitations. It will break for example jekyll serve (sidebar won't be updated on the fly on changes). It is however the best suggested, which makes me a bit troubled about how Jekyll fits to my needs.

I'm buiding a plugin now to preprocess the {{site.data}} to the format that I need so that I don't have to build the strings for every page separately in liquid. I noticed that these upped the rendereing time a lot more than I would have expected.